# Debug Nginx caching

Tags: nginx, cache, http-headers

I want to determine when I am getting cache hits or misses. Preferably, this would be a header, like

```
X-Cache: HIT
```

or

```
X-Cache: MISS
```

How can I do this with Nginx (a reverse proxy for the upstream server)?

Answer (score 4):

Per the answer [here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,214292,214293#msg-214293):

```
add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
```